# Localization and obstacle avoidance

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My system currently has

1. Wheel encoders that give encoder counter and rpm
2. Lidar which publishes /laserscan
3. QR code based pose detection using a high fps camera

I am trying to localize the robot as accurately as possible and use the lidar to avoid obstacles. I have some questions on this.

1. Is wheel odometry and qr based pose good enough or do i need an imu and additional sensors to localize the robot better?
2. What is the simplest way to perform obstacle avoidance using a lidar?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295827/localization-and-obstacle-avoidance/) by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For your first question, if you look over at hector_slam or gmapping, both can easily be used without an IMU (hector_slam doesn't even require wheel odometry) and can localize quite well.

For your second question, I would recommend looking over at the navigation stack as move_base has obstacle avoidance built into it, all you need to do is publish a target pose for move_base to run. The navigation stack also has some great tutorials on setting up everything for your robot so it is likely the simplest way that you can run obstacle avoidance.

---

Originally posted by [Joseph Dyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/36131/joseph-dyer/) with karma: 31 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0